# Random number generator game

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

void Guess(int Answer,int guess)
{
    if(guess!=Answer)
    {
        if(guess<Answer && guess!=Answer)
        {
            cout<<"The number is higher, try again"<<endl;
            cin>>guess;
        }
        else
            if(guess>Answer && guess!=Answer)
                {
                    cout<<"The number is lower, try again"<<endl;
                    cin>>guess;
                }
    }

}

int main()
{
    int Answer,guess;
    Answer=rand()%100;
    cout<<Answer<<endl;
    cout<<"Guess the number from 1 to 100"<<endl;
    cin>>guess;
    while(Answer!=guess)
       {
            Guess(Answer,guess);
            if(Answer==guess)
                break;
       }
       if(guess==Answer)
        cout<<endl<<"Congratulations, you guessed the number, it was "<<Answer<<" !";
}
```

So, this is the code I made after I learned some basic functions, you can probably tell that it is supposed to generate a random number, and then you have to guess what the number is, but I have a few problems:

1. it generates the same random number
2. If you don't guess it right the first time, the code keeps going forever even if at some point u guess the number.
3. If you guess a higher number, let's say 50 and the answer if 40, even if u then guess 30 it still says the number is lower when it's supposed to say higher.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: `void Guess(int Answer,int guess)` You need to pass parameters by reference to get these values outside of your function: `void Guess(int& Answer,int& guess)`

Comment: I'd recommend you should consult a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) before asking here next time.

Comment: Please make an answer an accept it instead of editing the title.

Answer (score 1):

Changed `void Guess(int Answer,int guess)` to `void Guess(int& Answer,int& guess)` and added  `srand ( time(NULL) );` at the start of int main to prevent the same number to be generated